# How can I create a Numpy Array that is much bigger than my RAM from 1000s of CSV files?

Tags: python, numpy, ram

I have 1000s of CSV files that I would like to append and create one big numpy array. The problem is that the numpy array would be much bigger than my RAM. Is there a way of writing a bit at a time to disk without having the entire array in RAM?

Also is there a way of reading only a specific part of the array from disk at a time?

Comment: It is theoratically impossible. Though if you use windows OS, you can make your storage 'act' like a RAM. But it will make your program significiantly slower. Tell us what you want to use the numpy array for, and we will be able to give you a practical solution.  :)

Comment: Look at lil_matrix or csr_matrix documentation. Maybe you can change your numpy to this format

Comment: Check out Dask (a flexible library for parallel computing in Python):  https://dask.org -- it supports NumPy, Pandas and Scikit-Learn, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When working with numpy and large arrays, there are several approaches depending on what you need to do with that data.

The simplest answer is to use less data. If your data has lots of repeating elements, it is often possible to use a [sparse array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html) from scipy because the two libraries are heavily integrated.

Another answer (IMO: the correct solution to your problem) is to use a [memory mapped array](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html). This will let numpy only load the necessary parts to ram when needed, and leave the rest on disk. The files containing the data can be simple binary files created using any number of methods, but the built-in python module that would handle this is [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html). Appending more data would be as simple as opening the file in append mode, and writing more bytes of data. Make sure that any references to the memory mapped array are re-created any time more data is written to the file so the information is fresh.

Finally is something like compression. Numpy can compress arrays with [`savez_compressed`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.savez_compressed.html) which can then be opened with `numpy.load`. Importantly, compressed numpy files cannot be memory-mapped, and must be loaded into memory entirely. Loading one column at a time may be able to get you under the threshold, but this could similarly be applied to other methods to reduce memory usage. Numpy's built in compression techniques will only save disk space not memory. There may exist other libraries that perform some sorts of streaming compression, but that is beyond the scope of my answer.

**Here is an example of putting binary data into a file then opening it as a memory-mapped array:**

```
import numpy as np

#open a file for data of a single column
with open('column_data.dat', 'wb') as f:
    #for 1024 "csv files"
    for _ in range(1024):
        csv_data = np.random.rand(1024).astype(np.float) #represents one column of data
        f.write(csv_data.tobytes())

#open the array as a memory-mapped file
column_mmap = np.memmap('column_data.dat', dtype=np.float)

#read some data
print(np.mean(column_mmap[0:1024]))

#write some data
column_mmap[0:512] = .5

#deletion closes the memory-mapped file and flush changes to disk.
#  del isn't specifically needed as python will garbage collect objects no
#  longer accessable. If for example you intend to read the entire array,
#  you will need to periodically make sure the array gets deleted and re-created
#  or the entire thing will end up in memory again. This could be done with a
#  function that loads and operates on part of the array, then when the function
#  returns and the memory-mapped array local to the function goes out of scope,
#  it will be garbage collected. Calling such a function would not cause a
#  build-up of memory usage.
del column_mmap

#write some more data to the array (not while the mmap is open)
with open('column_data.dat', 'ab') as f:
    #for 1024 "csv files"
    for _ in range(1024):
        csv_data = np.random.rand(1024).astype(np.float) #represents one column of data
        f.write(csv_data.tobytes())
```

Comment: But how can I make the massive array in the first place? For example, I have 25GB of RAM. I have 1500 CSV files that when loaded will total about 50GB. 

I want to load all 1500 CSV files to make the one massive array, but I can't because they won't all fit on to my RAM at once. 

My idea was to make a for loop and np.vstack to add the contents of each CSV file into an array...

Comment: @lara_toff there are several ways to get your data into a file. I already mentioned `struct` in my answer, and numpy also offers the `tobytes` method of arrays which returns raw binary that can be written to a binary file. I have written up a quick example of doing just that.

Comment: OK so just to confirm in the "write some data" section I could do a np.vstack to add to the memmap?

Comment: Any modifications you do to the memmap will remain in RAM until you close the file as explained in the super long comment at the end of the example. Numpy arrays are not designed to change size ever, so things like vstack generally make a copy of the data in question and create an entire new object. The method I demonstrated should not consume any more memory than the data from each individual csv at a time (plus whatever overhead for python itself, and buffered file writing done by the OS).

Comment: @lara_toff there's a lot of detailed explanations with examples on memory-mapped arrays in the documentation I linked.

Comment: OK but does that example you gave actually add to the size of the array?

Comment: @lara_toff there's nothing special about the file structure. Just make sure the mmap is closed, then it in append mode, and write more binary data.

Comment: OK i got it working but when i go to slice it from disk it is very slow... Is there a faster way?

Comment: @lara_toff There are a lot of ways slowdowns can happen. You might do well to ask in a separate post. If you're using spinning rust, get an ssd...

Comment: @Aaron What is the difference between creating the file using Python `struct` module and making a `.npy` file using `numpy.lib.format.open_memmap`?